# How to append query string arguments to URLs of script/JS files written in Require JS through script/Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require

Looking to query string arguments appended to URLs in Require JS project.

Comment: Try to explore webpack

Comment: This question IS clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a version number in each file URL using requirejs. You can set the value of version in `"urlArgs"` property of JSON object and pass this object in `require.config`.

Please see below code.

```
var version = "1.0";
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/scripts",
    paths: {
        "jquery": "jquery-2.2.1",
        "bootstrap": "jquery.bootstrap"
    },
    urlArgs: "v=" +  version
});

require(["jquery", "bootstrap"], function (jquery, bootstrap) {
    jquery("#id_div").html("Hello RequireJS!!!");
});
```

For more details, you can view documentation of [urlArgs](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs).